# Отсутствие запятой перед «чтобы»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

**Я не то чтобы претендую на это — просто так захотелось.**

Почему не ставится запятая перед "чтобы"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я **не то чтобы** претендую на это — просто так захотелось.*

[Знаки препинания в цельных по смыслу сочетаниях с подчинительными союзами или союзными словами (п. 2)](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=430):

**запятая не ставится** в неразложимых сочетаниях с отрицательными и ограничительными частицами *не только что, не то что, **не то чтобы**, не иначе как, только что не, только и... что, не так чтобы* и др.
*И вдруг одна фраза мне не понравилась, даже **не то чтобы** не понравилась, просто приковала внимание* (Зерн.).

*Он **не то чтобы** к славе стремился —

просто жил, искушая судьбу...*
Б. Окуджава

Часто используется двойной союз [**не то чтобы... а (но)**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/12845/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B..._%D0%B0_%28%D0%BD%D0%BE%29) — в этом случае запятая в предложении ставится только перед второй частью союза.
*Выражение **не то чтобы** жалости, **а** сумрачной озабоченности появилось на лице генерала, и он вдруг заторопился* (А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия).